# Where to start an integration test database with Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Instead of using JUnit `@ClassRule`s to start docker [TestContainers](https://testcontainers.org) for our integration test database, we let Spring do it with `ApplicationContextInitializer`s.
Benefits :

- start only 1 container for all "integration test" classes in a maven module thanks to *TestContext* caching (JUnit `ClassRule` and have each test class start a new container)
- also works when launching a single test class from the IDE (unlike a JUnit `ClassRule` in a `TestSuite`)
- Resulting properties are injected early into the context : database IP, port, credentials... this way we don't override beans (`DataSource`, `Session`, etc), we use the same configuration classes as the production application
- the container object created is added to the context as a bean, so testing code can access it

Simplified example :

```
public class RedisContainerInitializer implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext>, ApplicationListener<ContextClosedEvent> {

    private GenericContainer<?> container;

    @Override
    public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx) {
        container = new GenericContainer<>("redis:3.2.12-alpine").withExposedPorts(6379);
        container.start();

        // Inject properties
        TestPropertyValues props = TestPropertyValues.of(
            "spring.redis.host=" + container.getContainerIpAddress(),
            "spring.redis.port=" + container.getMappedPort(6379));
        props.applyTo(ctx);

        // Register this object as a bean, 
        // so testing code can access the container
        ctx.getBeanFactory().registerSingleton("redisContainer", this);

        // Make this instance receive Spring context "Close" events
        ctx.addApplicationListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextClosedEvent event) {
        container.close();
    }

    // getter, other irrelevant methods

}
```

**Question** : Using an `ApplicationContextInitializer` works but is it the "Spring way" to do so ?

If not, what kind of Spring Bean could be loaded early enough to inject properties that will be used by Spring Boot starters ?

At some point we used the Spring Cloud Bootstrap context, but users shouldn't need Spring Cloud to run integration tests.

Comment: Why not use `application-test.properties` to inject the test database details? If you need to launch the container as part of the integration test, you can create a script to launch the container and then run the Gradle task, right?

Comment: We have many integration test classes per application, and we want to be able to launch a single test from the IDE, multiple tests from the IDE, or multiple tests from maven/gradle. Using maven/gradle plugins, you can only launch tests using maven/gradle.